# Sync data between controller and dataobject

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got an angular controller (TimeCtrl) and a factory (DataService) that manages the data across some other controllers.

In TimeCtrl there are variables like $scope.dateFrom and $scope.dateTo. I want to make them share one memory space with the corresponding variables in the DataService (wacht.dateFrom and wacht.dateTo).

I don't want to have multiple watcher, which look for changes in the DateFrom Input to change it also in the DataService.

In short: A var should share it's value with another, without a sync func.

Is there a solution?

Things like

```
$scope.dateTo = DataService.getWacht().dateTo = '';
```

in the TimeCtrl don't work like expected.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: could you please share your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple if you use object and assign it as property on controller and factory instance.

You can do it like this:

```
angular
    .module('app', []);

angular
    .module('app')
  .controller('Example', function (exFactory) {
    this.obj = exFactory.obj;
  });

angular
    .module('app')
  .factory('exFactory', function () {
    return {
        obj: {
        x: 0
      }
    };
  });
```

For full example look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rnvLerqj/